# Shell Script Jenkins 401 error

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to run a Script in Jenkins to know the status of our staging server, So the script works perfectly as I want, when execute in CLI.

The script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
   hostlist=(s-exe1.cv.us s-exe2.cv.us s-exe3.cv.us s-exe4.cv.us)
   for host in "${hostlist[@]}"; do
    status=$(curl -sLI -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" "$host")
    case "$status" in
    200) echo "INFO: ssh on $host responding [Looks Good]" ;;
    *) echo "ERROR: $host responded with $status"[ Ooops Something Went 
        Wrong] ;;
      esac
     printf "%s\n" "$status"
   done
```

But when I build the project in the Jenkins I get 401 error as follows:

```
Started by timer
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Staging-Server-Status
[Staging-Server-Status] $ /bin/bash /tmp/hudson3637650861266439787.sh
ERROR: s-exe1.cv.us responded with 401[ Ooops Something Went Wrong]
401
ERROR: s-exe2.cv.us responded with 401[ Ooops Something Went Wrong]
401
ERROR: s-exe3.cv.us responded with 401[ Ooops Something Went Wrong]
401
ERROR: s-exe4.cv.us responded with 401[ Ooops Something Went Wrong]
401
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Can somebody please help to get rid of this 401 error in Jenkins?

Comment: I guess the user who runs the CLI script and the user who runs the Jenkins build is not the same, is it?

Comment: Nope its same! And thats me!

Comment: I'd use some program options to gather more data. [Curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) supports a verbosity switch, as well as writing stdout/stderr to a file. For testing purposes I'd use only one host in `hostlist`.